# What can be inferred about this residuals plot?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a residuals plot that looks like this:

[image]

The question I have is this:

[image]

Why is that answer correct? Reading the scatterplot, how do I know it's right skewed? It looks like there are more extreme residuals to the negative... so it's left skewed right? Is that's what's false?

Is a scatterplot of the residuals like this necessary before doing multiple regression? If so, why?

The X ax

Comment: "Which of the following statements is an ***incorrect*** analysis of the residual plots and conditions?" Correct answer is the incorrect analysis.

Comment: In fairness to you, the residuals are not really normally distributed either, they just don't show a particularly grievous bias. They seem fairly left-tailed in my opinion.